# Multiple definitions of a non-template class vs. a template class

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, linker

Why do compilers complain about a non-template class defined in multiple .cpp files but are fine with a template class the definition of which is duplicated across various .cpp files (via inclusion of the .inl file of the class), even if the class is explicitly instantiated in even multiple .cpp files?

Comment: Perhaps you should post the compiler's complaint and the code that generated it, so it's clear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template functions are inline, and inline functions are allowed to be defined in multiple compilation units as long as each definition is identical.

Comment: Does it mean, in turn, that marking a function of a template class (or just a template function) with `inline` is totally pointless as it's already qualified as inline?

Comment: @DesmondHume, I think so but I usually define my template functions in the class declaration so I'm not sure.

Comment: All functions defined inside a class definition are implicitly inline, but I don't believe template functions in general are. There's just a similar rule for template functions allowing them to be defined in multiple translation units.

Answer (score 3):

The non-template case is because in that scenario your program violates the one definition rule so the linker (not compiler) will complain about multiple definitions.

For templates on the other hand, the language specifies that this must work and the linker sorts out what to do. I'm not 100% sure if an explicit template instantiation should be treated the same as a non-template function though.

Comment: explicitly instantiating a template in multiple translation units is handled just like implicit instantiations in each TU.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  He asked about classes, and you _can_ (and must) have multiple definitions of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Do all compilers complain, always?  I've never seen one which did, and
the standard doesn't allow it: you're allowed to define a class or a
template once in each translation unit, as long as all of the
definitions are identical.  In fact, you're required to define the class
in every translation unit which uses it in a way that requires it to be
a complete type.  C++ does not have any mechanism for exporting class
definitions to other translation units.

Are you sure you're not confusing classes with functions.  You're not
allowed to define a function more than once, unless it is inline.  You
still have to define a function template in each translation unit which
uses it, and the same rules apply for function templates as for classes
and class templates.

Note that if you violate these rules, by defining the function in more
than one translation unit, or by the definitions of the classes or
templates not being tokenwise identical (after preprocessing, and
including name binding), then you have undefined behavior.  The compiler
(actually the linker) may complain about it, but it's not required: most
complain about multiple definitions of a function, but I don't know of
any which complain when the class or template definitions differ between
translation units.

Comment: Defining a non-template classes non-inline member functions in multiple translation units is not allowed.

Comment: @bames53 Defining a non-inline function, member or not, in multiple translation units is undefined behavior.  That may have been what he meant, but what he asked about was defining a class, not a function.